# How to use next auth to authenticate through a custom Spring API library and endpoints

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, authentication, next.js, next-auth

I am a newbie to Next.js and moving my front end from React to Next (v4). I've already developed a back end using Spring which connects to a MySQL database hosted on Azure. The API is fully tested and functional on Postman and a React front end. The API includes endpoints allowing for authentication. The API also generates a JWT token.

### Moving the front end from React to Next js

In trying to move the front end from React, authentication is the first problem being faced. I chose to try to next_auth, but there seems to be some problems in implementing next_auth using username and password credentials.

### Next auth for authenticating with Spring / Java REST APIs

The above leads me to ask if Next auth is even suitable for authenticating with Spring APIs in the first place? Or if a custom method (ie: standard React) would be better? The [Next auth documentation](https://next-auth.js.org/providers/credentials) seems to prefer using built-in methods like Google, Twitter, etc, with less support for custom credentials methods.

### Similar questions on SOF

I didn't find many similar questions on this specific use case. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69902602/how-to-securely-connect-my-next-js-frontend-with-next-auth-to-my-springboot-back) is the only question I found that talks about Next auth and Spring APIs. There are no answers to the question.

The closest thing to my problem is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64587059/how-to-implement-credentials-authorization-in-next-js-with-next-auth). It says the problem is about the configuration of the JWT token and callback. I followed the directions but it didn't solve the problem.[This question](https://next-auth.js.org/providers/credentials) is about connecting Next auth to a Spring boot API. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66349652/next-auth-credentials) is generally about how to configure and use Credentials provider.

Based on all of this, I tried the below:

## React code (including Postman signature)

The following code in React works fine with the API. I have also extracted the Postman signature in the fetch method.

```
const AuthForm = () => {

const emailInputRef = useRef();
const passwordInputRef = useRef();
const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState(true);
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
const [isAdmin, setIsAdmin] = useState(false);

const authCtx = useContext(AuthContext);

const switchAuthModeHandler = () => {
setIsLogin((prevState) => !prevState);
};

const submitHandler = (event) => {
event.preventDefault();

const enteredEmail = emailInputRef.current.value;
const enteredPassword = passwordInputRef.current.value;

// optional: Add validation

setIsLoading(true);

if (isLogin) {

  // Postman signature here

  var myHeaders = new Headers();
  myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  
  var urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
  urlencoded.append("username", enteredEmail);
  urlencoded.append("password", enteredPassword);

  var requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: myHeaders,
    body: urlencoded,
    redirect: 'follow'
  };

  fetch(API_LOGIN_URL, requestOptions)
    .then((res) => {
      setIsLoading(false);
      if (res.ok) {
        return res.json();
      } else {
        return res.json().then((data) => {
          let errorMessage = 'Authentication failed!';
          throw new Error(errorMessage);
        });
      }
    })
    .then((data)=> {
      authCtx.login(data.access_token);
      const processedData = JSON.stringify(data);
      console.log("Admin status "+ processedData);
     for(let i = 0; i < processedData.length; i++) {
            if(processedData.includes("ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN")) {
            console.log("Found Admin"); 
            authCtx.adminAccess(true);
          } 
          if(processedData.includes("ROLE_USER")) {
            console.log("Found User");
            break;
          }
          else {
            console.log("Not Found");
          }
    }})
    .catch((err) => {
      alert(err.message);
    });
  }
};

return (
<section className={classes.auth}>
  <h1>{isLogin ? 'Login' : 'Sign Up'}</h1>
  <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
    <div className={classes.control}>
      <label htmlFor='email'>Your Email</label>
      <input type='email' id='email' required ref={emailInputRef} />
    </div>
    <div className={classes.control}>
      <label htmlFor='password'>Your Password</label>
      <input type='password' id='password' required ref={passwordInputRef} />
    </div>
    <div className={classes.actions}>
      {!isLoading && <button>{isLogin ? 'Login' : 'Create Account'}</button>}
      {isLoading && <p>Sending request</p>}
      <button
        type='button'
        className={classes.toggle}
        onClick={switchAuthModeHandler}
      >
        {isLogin ? 'Create new account' : 'Login with existing account'}
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
 </section>
 );
};

export default AuthForm;
```

## Next.js Application Code

### [...nextauth].js

```
  export default NextAuth({
  session: {
  strategy: "jwt",
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 30 days
  },
  providers: [
  CredentialsProvider({
  name: 'credentials',
  credentials: {
    Username: {label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: 'app@apptest.com'},
    Password: {label: "Password", type: "password"}
  },
  async authorize(credentials, req) {

     // extracted from Postman 
  var myHeaders = new Headers();
  myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  
  
  var urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
  urlencoded.append("Username", credentials.Username);
  urlencoded.append("Password", credentials.Password);

  var requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: myHeaders,
    body: urlencoded,d
    redirect: 'follow'
  };

const user = fetch(API_LOGIN_URL, {
  requestOptions
  })

console.log("Credentials are: " + credentials.Username)
if (user) {

// Any object returned will be saved in `user` property of the JWT
return user
} else {
// If you return null or false then the credentials will be rejected
return null
// You can also Reject this callback with an Error or with a URL:
// throw new Error('error message') // Redirect to error page
// throw '/path/to/redirect'        // Redirect to a URL
 }
  
 },

  })],

callbacks: {
 async session({ session, token, user }) {
  session.user.id = token.id;
  session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
  return session;
 },
async jwt({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) {
if (user) {
  token.id = user.id;
}
if (account) {
  token.accessToken = account.access_token;
}
  return token;
},

}
}

)
```

Authform.js (login form)

```
import { useState, useRef, useContext } from 'react';
import classes from './AuthForm.module.css';
import { signIn } from 'next-auth/react';
import { API_LOGIN_URL } from '../Constants';
import { redirect } from 'next/dist/server/api-utils';

  function AuthForm () {
   const emailInputRef = useRef();
   const passwordInputRef = useRef();


 async function submitHandler (event) {
 event.preventDefault();

const enteredEmail = emailInputRef.current.value;
const enteredPassword = passwordInputRef.current.value;

  const result = await signIn('credentials', {
   redirect: false,
   username: enteredEmail,
   password: enteredPassword,
   callbackUrl: `${window.location.origin}`

  });  
  console.log("The email " + enteredEmail);

    console.log("Result is: " + result.error);
 }
    
return (
  <section className={classes.auth}>
       <h1>Login</h1>
    <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
    <div className={classes.control}>
      <label htmlFor='username'>Your Email</label>
      <input type='email' id='username' required ref={emailInputRef} />
    </div>
    <div className={classes.control}>
      <label htmlFor='password'>Your Password</label>
      <input
        type='password'
        id='password'
        required
        ref={passwordInputRef}
      />
    </div>
    <div className={classes.actions}>
      <button>Login</button>
      <button
        type='button'
        className={classes.toggle}
     >
        
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
 </section>
 );


 }
   export default AuthForm;
```

## Errors

### On the front end

When actually logging in, I get no errors. If I refresh the browser after restarting the application I get:

> [next-auth][warn][NO_SECRET]
> https://next-auth.js.org/warnings#no_secret
> [next-auth][error][JWT_SESSION_ERROR]
> https://next-auth.js.org/errors#jwt_session_error decryption operation
> failed {   message: 'decryption operation failed',   stack:
> 'JWEDecryptionFailed: decryption operation failed\n' +

### The back end

The login actually does reach the back end point (when monitoring the API terminal), but it gives null for the user name and password values.

### Main questions

1. Is Next auth the right framework to authenticate to a Spring API or is it better to write a custom authentication method (or even stick to using React)?
2. What is wrong with the above code?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi jay tai. Did you manage to figure out your main questions?

Answer (score 1):

In the credentials you have mentioned *username* but in the form it's *email*?

Can you update the `async authorize(credentials, req)` code to the below & try -

```
const payload = {
    email: credentials.email, // make sure this field is mapped correctly
    password: credentials.password,
};

const res = await fetch(API_LOGIN_URL, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(payload),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US',
    },
});

const user = await res.json();
```

Also the [signIn](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#signin) method's signature seems to be incorrect -

Syntax

```
signIn('credentials', { redirect: false, password: 'password' })
signIn('email', { redirect: false, email: 'bill@fillmurray.com' })
```

Usage

```
const result = await signIn('credentials', {
    headers: myHeaders,
    body: urlencoded,
   redirect: false
  });
```

Please update to

```
const res = await signIn('credentials', {
 redirect: false,
 email: values.email,
 password: values.password,
 callbackUrl: `${window.location.origin}`, // if required
});
```

Comment: Thanks AG. I updated my code based on your answer. I made everything consistent in terms of username instead of email. I even tried hardcoding values in the credential mapping for the username and password. I also tried to hardcode the same values in the Authform. Unfortunately none of this has so far solved any of the errors I described. The front end is still sending null values to the API. I am still getting exactly the same errors. Any suggestions on my updated code and most recent attempts? Thanks again.

Comment: What is the postman & react front end request signature which are giving successful result? Please share.

Comment: I updated the question with the React code and Postman signature. Let me know if it is clear. Thank you.

Comment: Still can't see what object you are passing to fetch or postman. In the `fetch(API_LOGIN_URL, requestOptions)` - what does `console.log(requestOptions)` prints?

Comment: Sorry. I accidentally forgot to include it. I have updated the code and it should be there now.